# What is the limit of metadata components in 1GMP or 2GMP?

Tags: managed-package, limits, isv, 2gmp, 1gmp

What is the limit of metadata components in 1GMP or 2GMP?

Yesterday I talked to my former colleague about the limitation of number of metadata components available for a single package and that metadata components for 2GMP are counted differently, like one Custom Object is counted as one metadata component for 1GMP but as many metadata components in 2GMP (each field and piece of the custom object is counted separately).

But exactly what is the value of that limit?

Is this possible to find out the current usage of this limit?

Answer (score 2):

Per [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm)

```
Maximum number of files in AppExchange packages 35,000
Maximum number of files in packages 10,000
```